# What happens when you don't enter a time in the time circuits?

Tags: back-to-the-future

The time circuits in the DeLorean have the capacity to enter times *and* dates.  My question is then: **if you were to enter a *date* and not a *time*, what *time* would you arrive at on the specified date?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually happens in the first film.  When demonstrating the DeLorean to Marty, Doc goes and enter several dates **without times**, notably November 5 1955 - recall he doesn't actually provide a date.  **The time defaulted to 06:00 i.e. 6 AM**.

As per the [BTTF Wiki page on time circuits](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Time_circuits):

> Then, Doc Brown gave a third example by setting them to the day that
>   he invented time travel, November 5, 1955. **Because Doc only set a day,
>   month, and year, the time defaulted to 6:00 a.m.**

I am not exactly sure *where* they arrived at the exact time of 6 AM, but if you recall when Marty arrived in 1955 it was early morning (not long after he arrived it the sun began to rise).  This is supported by this excerpt from [the script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/bttf4th.pdf):

> EXT THE DELOREAN - **MORNING**
>
> tears along the dirt road and out onto the MAIN (PAVED) ROAD.
>
> EXT. STREET - DAY
>
> The DeLorean pulls into frame and stops.  Marty's gull wing door opens, revealing Mary's shocked expression...

That excerpt indicates to me that by the time Marty got to the road, the sun had risen, so we are talking in the vicinity of sunrise on that particular day.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems to use 6 AM *local time*, rather than GMT or something.  I wonder if it adjusts for DST.